# Why isn't case a problem when compiling this Java file?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, case-sensitive

If I write a Java class as follows:
`public class Test {}`

...and save it in a file with the same class name, but different case, like this:
`test.java`

...then why is it possible to compile it successfully as follows:
`javac Test.java`?

I thought the name of a public class and its file name must be the same, **including in case**. I am surprised I did not get a "file not found" error. What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are compiling in an operating system with a file system that is not case sensitive like Windows the compiler will not notice the difference. That's because for the file system test.java and Test.java are the same file.